# extension problem: Unexpected token in JSON at position 5

Tags: vscode-extensions, github-issues

I had a few problems these days with VS Code, when I tried to add an extension it would say in the output:

> Unexpected token  in JSON at position 5

I haven't thought anything about it since it may have been an update problem so I left it, now it was updated (I forgot when) but since I was in a vacation I didn't try to test it, and the same issue, I searched on Google, GitHub issues, Stackoverflow, pretty much every site about programming, there was nothing (well I only stayed like 5 mins on each site but it means it isn't a common problem which makes me think no one will respond but hey, at least I tried, right?)

[image: how the problem looks like:]

I re-installed VS Code while also deleting every file of it (my programs folders are on backup) and then checked on Google (it only had HTML stuff), on GitHub (same as Google or something else similar to my problem) so yeah I need help from someone because the internet isn't with me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Images of text aren't accessible or searchable and should be augmented with the text they contain or replaced by it.